# UICollectionView didSelectItemAt never triggers

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4

In my VC I have a view that pulls up from the bottom. I setup and add a UICollectionView in the viewDidLoad():

```
//Add and setup the collectionView
collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
collectionView?.register(PhotoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "photoCell")
collectionView?.delegate = self
collectionView?.dataSource = self
collectionView?.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9771530032, green: 0.7062081099, blue: 0.1748393774, alpha: 1)
collectionView?.allowsMultipleSelection = false
collectionView?.allowsSelection = true
pullUpView.addSubview(collectionView!)
pullUpView.bringSubview(toFront: collectionView!)
```

The UICollectionView Delegate methods are in an extension, for now in the same codefile as the VC:

```
//MARK: - Extension CollectionView
extension MapVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imagesArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photoCell", for: indexPath) as? PhotoCell {
            let imageFromIndex = imagesArray[indexPath.item]
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: imageFromIndex )
            cell.addSubview(imageView)
            return cell
        } else {
            return PhotoCell()
        }
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("selected")
        //Create PopVC instance, using storyboard id set in storyboard
        guard let popVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popVC") as? PopVC else { return }
        popVC.passedImage = imagesArray[indexPath.row]
        present(popVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

The problem is that when I tap on a cell nothing happens. I've put a print statement inside the didSelectItemAt method, but that never gets printed. So, my cells never get selected or at least  the didSelectItemAt method never gets triggered!

Been debugging and trying for hours, and I can't see what's wrong. Any help appreciated. Perhaps someone could open mijn project from Github to see what's wrong, if that is allowed ?

UPDATE:
Using Debug View Hierarchy, I see something disturbing: Each photoCell has multiple (many!) UIImageViews. I think that should be just one UIImageView per photoCell. I don't know what is causing this behaviour?

[Debug View Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AhmI.png)

Comment: if you long press, does it work then?

Comment: where is the link of github

Comment: Long Press doesn't work either, not in simulator, not on a physical device

Comment: Here's the Github Link
https://github.com/Gakkienl/Pixel-City

Comment: Your project on github doesn't compile due to missing podfile and dependencies

Comment: The problem of multiple image view is caused by the fact you add `UIImageView` in `collectionView(_: cellForItemAt:)`

Comment: I am new at Github, can't see how to add the podfiles to a commit. Trying to figure out how to upload the whole project in one go again ...
Also, added an image from debug view hierarchy

Comment: @Rico Crescenzio: Where should I add it then? But I'm following a online course and they do it exactly like I did and there it is just fine?

Comment: @Gakkie - you have several things going wrong... First, `cellForItemAt` will be called multiple times, particularly if you are animating your collection view into view. In `cellForItemAt` you are adding an image view as a subview *every time it is called*! It should only be added once, preferably inside its own class... and then `cellForItemAt` simply sets its `.image` property. I'd suggest making a separate project and figure out how to get your collectionView setup and working properly, and *then* integrate it into the full project.

Comment: which pod are in your Podfile?

Comment: @DonMag. I'll try that! But the source from myonline coarse does the same and does work as intended ?!?

Comment: Here is the complete project http://www.gakkie.nl/images/Pixel-City.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code, there are few problems:

First of all you have to change your PhotoCell implementation, and add your imageView inside the class, only when the cell is created. Your cell is not loading a XIB so you have to add the imageView in `init(frame:)`:

```
class PhotoCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var photoImageView: UIImageView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupCell()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupCell() {
        photoImageView = UIImageView()
        addSubview(photoImageView)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        photoImageView.frame = bounds // ensure that imageView size is the same of the cell itself
    }

}
```

After this change, in `cellForItem` method you can do `cell.photoImageView.image = imageFromIndex`.

The problem of didSelect not called is caused by the fact your `pullUpView`is always with height = 1, even if you're able to see the collectionView, it will not receive any touch.

- First add an IBOutlet of the height constraint of pullUpView in your MapVc
- When creating collection view, ensure the size of collection view is the same of the pullUpView, so it will be able to scroll; `collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: 300), collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)`

Then change `animateViewUp` and `animateViewDown` to this

```
func animateViewUp() {
    mapViewBottomConstraint.constant = 300
    pullUpViewHeightConstraint.constant = 300 // this will increase the height of pullUpView
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
@objc func animateViewDown() {
    cancelAllSessions()

    //remove previous loaded images and urls
    imagesArray.removeAll()
    imageUrlsArray.removeAll()

    mapViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0
    pullUpViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0 // this will reset height to 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

By doing all of this the swipe down gesture will not work anymore because the touch is intercepted and handled by the collection view, you should handle this manually.

However I suggest you to change the online course, there are a lot of things that I don't like about this code.

Comment: Thank you. I'll go and implement the changes you pointed out!

Comment: The pullUpView height constraint was indeed the culprit! I added an outlet for that and change the height in animateViewUp(). For now that does it, but I am going to implement your suggestions as well. Honestly, I am very curious about what you don't like about the course's code!

Comment: Yes, among the (many) problems with this code, the reason the cells were not "tap-able" is the height constraint on `pullUpView`. Instead of adding it as an IBOutlet and changing it, delete the Height constraint and add a Bottom constraint of `0` to safe-area. That will allow auto-layout to automatically change the height of `pullUpView` as needed (and you won't have to make multiple changes if you decide to adjust the area for your collection view).

Comment: I agree with @DonMag, however it's not good to add subviews in cellForItem since it's called every time a cell needs to be visible; I don't like mixing auto-layout and manually set view's position and size; the panGesture applied to the view is incorrect because it doesn't work: the collectionView scrolling will prevent the pan gesture trigger (but for this maybe the course will teach you how to handle)

Comment: @Gakkie please upvote/set as best answer if it helped you :D

Comment: I did! But i'm too new here for it to count ?

Comment: @Gakkie You can set as best answer

Comment: Like so ?
And I'm kinda worried I am learning Swift the wrong way now ...

Comment: Thank you, if you want to learn iOS development really good I suggest you to start reading (maybe not all) this: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920107415.do

Comment: Thank you! I used a book before, but I like a video course way better ... Must be a good one around I would think ...

Comment: Read a book is harder but explain more deeply everything